# application.current.properties doesn't persist value from service call (Asynchronous Method) in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to store object in isolated storage. I am using `Application.Current.Properties`.

Problem is when I store static string to isolated storage like

```
Application.Current.Properties["EC"] = "10008";
```

then it works perfectly but when I call service (Asynchronous method) and Fill the object it doesn't store persistently.

```
private async Task CallWebServiceForUserProfile(string EmpCode)
 {
     try
     {
         var response = await ServiceLayer.GetResponseFromWebService.GetResponse<ServiceLayer.ServiceClasses.Profile_RootObject>
                                          (ServiceLayer.ServiceURL.UserProfile + "UserId=" + EmpCode);
         if (response != null)
         {
             if (response.Flag == true)
             {
                 objProfile = new Profile();
                 objProfile.BranchCd = response.PrInfoList[0].BranchCd != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].BranchCd : string.Empty; ;
                 objProfile.CLBalance = response.PrInfoList[0].CLBalance != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].CLBalance : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.COFFBalance = response.PrInfoList[0].COFFBalance != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].COFFBalance : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.Designation = response.PrInfoList[0].Designation != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].Designation : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.ELBalance = response.PrInfoList[0].ELBalance != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].ELBalance : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.EmpCode = response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.EmpName = response.PrInfoList[0].EmpName != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].EmpName : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.Grade = response.PrInfoList[0].Grade != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].Grade : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.HOD = response.PrInfoList[0].HOD != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].HOD : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.HPLBalance = response.PrInfoList[0].HPLBalance != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].HPLBalance : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.LocCd = response.PrInfoList[0].LocCd != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].LocCd : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.ReportingTo = response.PrInfoList[0].ReportingTo != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].ReportingTo : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.Unit = response.PrInfoList[0].Unit != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].CLBalance : string.Empty;
                 objProfile.Photo = response.PrInfoList[0].Photo != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].Photo : null;
                 objProfile.Join_Dt = response.PrInfoList[0].Join_Dt != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].Join_Dt : string.Empty;

                 Application.Current.Properties["UserProfile"] = objProfile;
                 Application.Current.Properties.Add("UserProfile", objProfile);
                 Application.Current.Properties["EmployeeCode"] = response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode : string.Empty;
                 //await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
             }
             else if (response.Flag == false)
             {
                 await DisplayAlert(AppResources.LError, response.Message, "OK");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             await DisplayAlert(AppResources.LError, AppResources.LConnectionError, "OK");
         }
     }
     catch (WebException Exception)
     {
         await DisplayAlert(AppResources.LError, AppResources.LConnectionError, "OK");
     }
 }
```

I want to use this information when my application is start.

```
Profile objProfile = new Profile();

if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("UserProfile"))
{
    objProfile = Application.Current.Properties["UserProfile"] as Profile;

    if (objProfile.EmpCode != null)
    {
        MyEmployeeId = objProfile.EmpCode;
    }

    MainPage = new SideMenu();
}
else
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
}
```

As you can see in above code I have put following code to store data.

```
Application.Current.Properties["UserProfile"] = objProfile;
//Application.Current.Properties.Add("UserProfile", objProfile);
Application.Current.Properties["EmployeeCode"] = response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode != null ? response.PrInfoList[0].EmpCode : string.Empty;
```

I have also try but don't solve my problem.

```
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Every time Login-page is open at application start.

Is there any alternative way to solve this issue? I don't want to use SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize/deserialize your Profile object manually.

Please refer this link for example-
https://codemilltech.com/persist-whatever-you-want-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative way to solve this issue? I don't want to use SQLite.

Store persistent data needs native API support. You can register a [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/) for Store Settings Data and implement this service in different platforms.

For Android:
  You can leverage [ISharedPreference](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.ISharedPreferences/) to store data.

For iOS:
  You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/user-defaults/) to store app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xamarin Cross-platform Settings plugin